# If $f_n$ converges to $f $ in $p$-norm, then $f_n$ converges to $f$ in measure.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I want to prove that if $f_n$ converges to $f $ in $p$-norm, then  $f_n$ converges to $f$ in measure. This is the proof:

Suppose not. Then there exist $\epsilon>0,\delta> 0$ such that $μ \{x: |f_n —f|  > \epsilon\} > \delta$ for infinitely many $n$. But then $||f_n-f||_p> \epsilon δ^\frac{1}{p}$ for infinitely many $n$, giving a contradiction.

But I don't understand the last inequality. Please help me understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E_{n,\varepsilon} = \{x : |f_n(x)-f(x)| > \varepsilon$. If $\mu(E_{n,\varepsilon}) > \delta$ then

$$\int|f_n-f|^p\geqslant \int_{E_{n,\varepsilon}}|f_n-f|^p > \int_{E_{n,\varepsilon}} \varepsilon^p = \mu(E_{n,\varepsilon})\varepsilon^p>\varepsilon^p\delta, $$

and the desired inequality is obtained by raising both sides to the $\frac1p$ power.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a direct proof, rather than contradiction.

Choose $\epsilon>0$ and let $A_{n,\epsilon} = \{ x | |f_n(x) -f(x)| > \epsilon \}$.

Then
$\int |f-f_n|^p \ge \int_{A_{n,\epsilon}} |f-f_n|^p  \ge \epsilon^p \mu(A_{n,\epsilon})$, and so
${1 \over \epsilon^p}\|f-f_n\|^p \ge \mu(A_{n,\epsilon})$. It follows
that $\lim_n \mu(A_{n,\epsilon}) = 0$ and so $f_n$ converges to $f$ in measure.